# Book series about kids of retired heroes who have inherited their powers

Tags: story-identification, books

This series was about the son of two retired heroes who discovers he and his friends have powers as they’re all the kids of heroes.

The dad is based on the superman trope (strength, flight, etc.)

Everyone assumes the teen got his dad’s powers but it turns out he got the mom’s energy manipulation powers too.

Think was a hero and their son who had superspeed, but the kid lost his arm trying to phase at some point.

There’s a character kind of like Ironman, and his daughter(I think) takes over after he dies.

Does anyone know what this book series was called?

Comment: Do you remember in about what year you read this series?

Comment: What was Jupiter's Legacy based on?

Comment: @Jontia - "Children of superheroes" is a pretty common trope

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is [*The New Heroes*](https://www.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_New_Heroes) series of novels by Michael Carroll.

> Ten years later, Colin Wagner and Danny Cooper, the children of these superhumans are discovering their abilities and they soon learn that they have also inherited their parents' enemies. The teenagers are kidnapped in order to calibrate the machine that might take away their powers and stop a war that was prophesied by Danny's father, the man once known as Quantum. Danny was believed to be the cause of this war, and so he allowed the supervillain known as Façade to take his place to let Maxwell Dalton record his visions of the future as he broke down. They had hoped to avert it by stripping the world of superpowers ten years ago, but the machine was destroyed and Danny's powers continued to manifest. The new machine would be unstable, and potentially kill hundreds of thousands of people, but it was a risk they were willing to take. With the help of old heroes, including the frozen in time Renata Soliz (Diamond), they stop this from happening and have those behind the plot taken away. By the end of the book, they realise how much risk is involved in becoming superhuman, with Danny's arm now missing, his real father dead, and many lives irrevocably changed.
>
> [image]